# when I am passing the value of a string and an integer using javascript there will be an error

Tags: javascript

in this code when I am passing a value using an on the openModal function but when I am passing string and an int it shows an error "time.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" but when I am using response[i].event_id for the second value that I will pass to the openModal it will be doing just fine.

here's my code:

```
eventsList += '<li>' + response[i].event_name + ' <span class="delete-button" onclick="deleteEvent(' + response[i].event_id + ')">Delete</span> <span class="delete-button" onclick="openModal(' + response[i].event_id + ',' + response[i].event_name +')">Edit</span></li>';
```

function:

```
function openModal(value1, value2) {
var modal = $("#myModal");
modal.css("display", "block");

var input = document.getElementById('eventId');
input.value = value1;

var input2 = document.getElementById('eventName');
input2.value = value2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to manually add quotes around the string to prevent spaces or other characters in the string from causing issues.

```
'openModal(' + response[i].event_id + ',"' + response[i].event_name +'")'
```

But you should really use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event handlers.

Comment: thank you for the advice about using the addEventListener, but the answer still don't work. I already solved the error. I should have used \' rather than " to wrap around it.

Comment: @JosephCerbito Single or double quotes should not make a difference unless you have double quotes inside your string itself. But glad to hear that you solved it.